# laravel guzzle httpsocket parameters for ssl verify peer & host

Tags: laravel, cakephp, httprequest, guzzle

I have the following code in CakePHP. I need the same code in laravel using guzzle

```
$url = "https://xyz?";
$query ='first_name='. $data->FirstName .'&gender=""'. '&home_phone='. $data->HomePhone.'&ip_address='. $data->IPAddress.'&last_name='. $data->LastName.'&user_defined_url='. $result;

$HttpSocket = new HttpSocket(array('ssl_verify_peer' => false, 'ssl_verify_host' => false));
$post_response = $HttpSocket->get($url,$query);
$response = explode('&',$post_response->body);
```

I have converted it in laravel using guzzle but doesnt work. Following my code that Ive converted in laravel:

```
$client         =   new Client(['verify' => false ]);
$post_response  =   $client->get($url, $query);
$response       =   explode('&',$post_response->body);
```

Note: use GuzzleHttp\Client; is written at the top of file.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: It gives many errors in laravel.log & in rest-client I don't get the response. Some of errors in laravel.log being follows:
[2017-08-31 10:35:10] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array, string given, called in /var/www/html/laravel/clickmedia/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php on line 89 and defined' in /var/www/html/laravel/clickmedia/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php:128
#2 /var/www/html/laravel/clickmedia/app/Http/Controllers/ApiController.php(163): GuzzleHttp\Client->__call('get', Array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try like this,

```
$client = new Client();
$post_response  = $client->request('GET', $url, [
    'verify' => false,
    'form_params' => [
        'first_name' => $data->FirstName,
        'gender' => "", 
        'home_phone' => $data->HomePhone, 
        'ip_address' => $data->IPAddress, 
        'last_name' => $data->LastName, 
        'user_defined_url' => $result
    ]
]);
$response = explode('&',$post_response->body);
```

Instead of **form_params** you can use **query** for sending the parameters as query string.